# Existence of limits in a nonempty bounded set

Tags: real-analysis

Let be $ M \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ a nonempty bounded set. Then there are existing monotone convergent sequences $ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ and $ (b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ such that
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=\sup(M), \quad \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n=\inf(M)$$
and $ a_n,b_n\in M $ for all $ n\in \mathbb{N} $.

**My Idea:**

> Because $ M \subseteq \mathbb{R} $ is a nonempty bounded set there are already existing $ \sup(M) $ and $ \inf(M) $.
> Now define recursive sequences for $ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ and $ (b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ as follows:
> $$ x_n=\frac{a_n+\sup(M)}{2}\\[15pt]y_n=\frac{b_n+\inf(M)}{2} $$
> with arbitrary startvalues $ a_0,b_0\in M $.
>
> If $ x_n,y_n\in M $ then chose $  a_{n+1}=x_n $ and $ b_{n+1}=y_n $.
>
> If $ x_n,y_n\notin M $ then there existing $ a,b\in M $ with $$ x_n<a\leq \sup(M), \quad \inf(M)\leq b<y_n $$
> and chose $ a_{n+1}=a $ and $ b_{n+1}=b $.
>
> By this construction it follows $ a_n,b_n\in M $ for all $ n\in \mathbb{N} $.
> By Induction it follows that for all $ n\in \mathbb{N} $:
> $$ a_{n+1}\geq a_n,\quad b_{n+1}\leq b_n,\quad \inf(M)\leq a_n,b_n\leq \sup(M). $$
> So $ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ and $ (b_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ are monotone convergent sequences and the limits
> $$ g:=\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n,\quad \tilde{g}:=\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n $$
> are existing.

Now form here I have no idea to show at first that $ g,\tilde{g} $ are boundaries and if so how to show they are like in the conjecture.

Comment: My first idea is this: Assume $ g $ is not an upper 
bound. So there exists an $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ with $ g<a_n $. By construction $ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ is monotone increasing it follows inductive that $ g<a_m $ for all $ m\geq n $. So for all $ m\geq n $  $ g $  is a lower bound of this sequence. So it is $ g<\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n $ which is a contradiction. Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

Your basic idea is great.  You got bogged down in details.  But don't worry, students always do get lost in their own arguments at first, even though the initial idea was pushing in the correct direction.

Here is a simpler analysis.

**Step 1.** It is enough to prove that there is a  monotone  sequence $\{a_n\}$ of points in $M$ so that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \sup M$.  The case for the sequence $\{b_n\}$ and $\inf M$ is similar.  [See footnote [1].]

**Step 2.** Suppose that the point $m=\sup M$ belongs to $M$.  Then clearly the
sequence $a_n=m$ satisfies the required condition. [See footnote [2].]

**Step 3.** Suppose, in the other case, that  the point $m=\sup M$ does not belong  to $M$.  In that case there must exist a sequence of points $\{x_n\}$ in $M$ for which
$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \sup M$. [See footnote [3].]

**Step 4.** Select from the sequence $\{x_n\}$ a monotone subsequence and label it as
$\{a_n\}$.  The subsequence also converges to  $m=\sup M$. [See footnote [4].]

**FOOTNOTES:**

**[1]** Nice simplifying assumption. This is usually the case that two parts of a statement are similar enough to do this.  Most people just bluff.  You really should think for a while to make sure it really is similar.  There are notorious cases where something was not at all similar and needed a totally different argument.  Embarrassing when that happens.

**[2]** Separate into cases when it makes life easier. If the set $M$ was finite then the only sequence $\{a_n\}$ would be constant.

**[3]**  This is a standard fact about sups and infs.  Understand it and use it.  It is better to rely on it every time than to construct your sequences laboriously as you did.  If you feel uncertain about using some fact in an assignment and cannot cite a theorem in the text, then start your assignment this way: *"I will first prove the following lemma:..."*

**[4]** Again this is a standard fact, very useful.  You shouldn't have to construct your sequence with such an effort when you know that all sequences of real numbers have monotone subsequences. If you don't have that theorem in your text [you should have] then you can take this sequence
$\{x_n\}$ and describe how to select a monotone subsequence.  Your proof attempted this, but you crammed too much into a single step what with all the $x_n$, $y_n$, $a_n$, and $b_n$.  If you keep the steps separate your marker will follow easily and you won't get bogged down.